# ¿Cómo consigo el directorio a partir de la ruta completa de un fichero?

Tags: bash

Me gustaría almacenar la ruta del script en una variable pero sin su nombre.

He pensado hacer esto:

```
readlink -e $0
```

pero esto me mostraría por ejemplo:

```
/carpeta/carpeta/script.sh
```

y yo quiero solo esto:

```
/carpeta/carpeta/
```

La cosa es que pueda estar en cualquier carpeta y siempre pueda encontrar la ruta de la carpeta en la que está el script.

Comment: asociación: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6121091/

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' No entiendo tu comentario.  Algunas de mis respuestas han sido encontradas en SO en inglés, y si bien he puesto el propio enlace en la respuesta, ahora no se si he hecho lo correcto... ¿que quieres decir con **asociación**?  Tenia entendido que era permitido hacerlo mientras nuestras respuestas no se limitaran a una traduccion literal del ingles, sino que aportaramos algo diferencial. [Lo vi aqui](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/14/son-aceptables-las-traducciones-directas-de-respuestas-de-stackoverflow-en-ingl)

Comment: @masterguru es simplemente la manera de asociar las preguntas de SOes y SO, para que la gente que entre en la versión inglesa vea un enlace a la española si tiene el navegador en castellano. Recomiendo leer [Las preguntas de SO ya pueden asociarse con las de SOes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3960/83)

Comment: @masterguru por tanto, no es que no sea malo, es que es bueno :)

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' Estupendo! No lo sabia... Repasaré mis respuestas y en las que vea que coinciden dejare el comentario en la pregunta. Muchas gracias por la aclaración

Answer (score 6, accepted):

El comando que necesitas es `dirname`

```
path=$(readlink -e $0)

directorio=$(dirname $path)
```

Answer (score 1):

Algo que yo suelo usar es esto:

```
$ dirname "$(readlink -f <archivo>)"
```

Y para el archivo en curso he usado:

```
_DIRNAME="$( dirname "$( readlink -f "$0" )" )"
```

Y:

```
_DIRNAME=$( dirname "$( realpath -s "$0")" )
```

Si vemos lo que hace cada comando tenemos los siguiente.

#### *dirname*

Según mi interpretación de `dirname(1)`, el comando remueve el último componente de un nombre de archivo. Es decir:

```
$ echo "/folder1/folder2/"
/ruta/folder2/
$ echo "$(dirname "/folder1/folder2/")"
/folder1
```

De cierta manera no de muestra "la carpeta que contiene el archivo", sino que sólo elimina el último componente.

#### *readlink*

Según el manual, este comando resuelve los enlaces simbólicos o nombres canónicos de los archivos. Y con los parámetros:

- `-f`, sigue cada enlace simbólico de cada componente recursivemente. Lo característico de esta opción es que todos, **salvo el último componente deben existir**
- `-e`, este es semejante al anterior, salvo que **todos los componentes deben existir**
- `-m`, este es más libertino, y no requiere que ningún componente exista

Pongamos un ejemplo:

```
$ \ls -la --color
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 12 cuauhtli_elizalde wheel 384 Jan 13 00:01 .
drwxrwxrwt 23 root              wheel 736 Jan 12 23:53 ..
# Existen cada archivo simbólico y el archivo al que todos hacen referencia
-rw-r--r--  1 cuauhtli_elizalde wheel   0 Jan 12 23:54 e
lrwxr-xr-x  1 cuauhtli_elizalde wheel   3 Jan 12 23:56 e1 -> ./e
lrwxr-xr-x  1 cuauhtli_elizalde wheel   4 Jan 12 23:56 e2 -> ./e1
lrwxr-xr-x  1 cuauhtli_elizalde wheel   4 Jan 12 23:56 e3 -> ./e2
# No existe f, es decir, el archivo inicial del cual todos los enlaces fueron creados
lrwxr-xr-x  1 cuauhtli_elizalde wheel   3 Jan 12 23:55 f1 -> ./f
lrwxr-xr-x  1 cuauhtli_elizalde wheel   4 Jan 12 23:56 f2 -> ./f1
lrwxr-xr-x  1 cuauhtli_elizalde wheel   4 Jan 12 23:56 f3 -> ./f2
```

Y probando:

```
$ readlink -m no_existe         #  ¡Y nos devuelve el nombre
/private/tmp/enlaces/no_existe  #+ aunque no exista ni enlace
                                #+ ni archivo!

$ readlink -f f3
/private/tmp/enlaces/f  #  Nos devuelve el nombre ./f, aunque este 
                        #+ último no exista, sino es sólo hasta 
                        #+ donde el último enlace existente (f1) apunta

$ readlink -e f3  #  No devuelve nada, salvo un error 1
                  #+ porque no encontró el último archivo

$ readlink -e e3        #  Devuelve el último componente porque
/private/tmp/enlaces/e  #+ todos existen
```

#### La variable *$0*

Esta variable, según `bash(1)`, cuando se ejecuta desde la terminal, te da el nombre de la shell usada:

```
$ echo $0
-zsh  # En mi caso
```

Pero si la usas desde un script, te da el nombre del archivo que actua como ejecutable.

Entonces, cuando compones todos los comandos tenemos:

- `$0`, el **puro nombre del archivo**
- `readlink -e`, la **ruta** del nombre del archivo que debe existir
- `dirname`, de la ruta, **borramos el último componente** después de la diagonal

#### **realpath**

El comando `realpath` hace algo semejante a lo que hacemos con toda esa combinación de comandos.

Por ejemplo:

```
$ realpath -m f3  # nos da f, aunque no exista
/private/tmp/enlaces/f
$ realpath -e f3  # Nos da un error porque f no existe
realpath: f3: No such file or directory
$ realpath -s f3         #  Nos da el nombre del archivo
/private/tmp/enlaces/f3  #+ sin resolverlo recursivamente
```